# Batch file command to select user's path (user input) and create a folder quoted in command

Tags: batch-file, makefile, command, directory, user-input

I need a batch file command which will select user's directory path (user input) and it should create a directory which is quoted by me.

For example, if the user select the path "C:\New folder", then the batch file should create "C:New folder\Folder1\Folder2". The path "Folder1\Folder2" is my directory and it should create along with the user's path "C:New folder" by such as mkdir "Folder1\Folder2". This is for copying some files to that folder.

(QUESTION UPDATED) My code so far :

```
@echo off
set /p var=Enter destination folder:
mkdir "MyFolder\Folder1" %var%
xcopy file.exe "MyFolder\Folder1" %var%
```

But, it doesnt work anymore. It will create "MyFolder\Folder1" on the current directory only. But, the structure is exactly this is. The path "Myfolder\Folder1" should create along with the user's path. What should i do..? :(

Comment: Exactly what is your question?

Comment: updated the question. added one code and please check the code. the code will not work but the structure i means that the code exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script you have not mentioned where to create the myfolder...

The script should be something like below.

```
set /p var=Enter destination folder
mkdir %var%\sample1
```

Make sure the destination folder is proper.
Give a message on how the destination folder should look like.

You can even pass it as paramater and use `%1` in place of `%var%`.

Comment: My folder should create on user selected path. Anyway i wil try this. Thnx for help..

Comment: Can you please elobrate. User oath in the sense? we are doing the same here right. The value user enters is got in the 'var' variable and the folder is being created there only.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the user to do something like this on the command line when they run the script.

`yourscript folderpath`

to get this you can use a `%1` to check for the existence of user input and use that as your variable in the script.

Check out [www.ss64.com](http://www.ss64.com) for a great library of functions and scripting examples.
I learned a lot there.

You could also use `set/p` to ask a question and the answer would be saved as a variable.
I usually prefer this as the end user may not know to specify a parameter when using your script the first time.

Maybe look into powershell too as it is much more versatile than batch scripts.